Failed To Install UEFI dbx firmware update
When attempting to update my UEFI dbx firmware to version 371 (from 262), I get the following popup:


Failed to install firmware!
org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2derror_2dquark.Code13: failed to write data to efivarfs: Error writing to file descriptor: Invalid argument

I have a Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd. 730QED.

A question for what ever you are trying to update. The computer? An SSD drive you have not said. Edit the question and add some detail please.

Sorry for not listing this information, I am not very tech smart. I am only using this option for performance. I will edit my information to the best my ability.
